# Find group membership for user in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, active-directory

I'm writing a program in Visual Basic 2015 and I'm trying to code a program that will find all of the AD groups that a user is a member of and display them in a listbox. I will be including the option to export this to a .csv file afterwards. I can search by either sAMAccountName or by DN as I have both variables defined. I'm getting stumped, all I'm getting is null search results. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices
Imports System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
Public Class UserMembershipWin
Private Sub queryAD_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles queryAD.Click
    Dim username As String
    username = usernameBox.Text
    Dim emptybox
    emptybox = usernameBox.Text.Length
    If emptybox = 0 Then
        errormsg.Content = "*Required field"
    End If
    If emptybox > 0 Then
        Dim domain = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)
        Dim user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domain, username)
        Dim userDN
        userDN = user.DistinguishedName

        Dim ADEntry As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=domain,DC=com")
        Dim Groups As New Collection
        Dim mySearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(ADEntry)
        Dim arrList As New ArrayList()

        mySearcher.Filter = "(&(ObjectClass=User)(DN=" & userDN & "))"
        mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("MemberOf")

        Dim searchResults As SearchResultCollection = mySearcher.FindAll()
        If searchResults.Count = 0 Then
            errormsg.Content = "Invalid username"
        End If
        If searchResults.Count > 0 Then
            Dim group As New DirectoryEntry(searchResults(0).Path)
            For Each member As Object In group.Properties("MemberOf")
                userlistbox.Items.Add(member)
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have replicated your problem and found that by changing the below line the searcher returned values:

```
mySearcher.Filter = "(&(ObjectClass=User)(distinguishedName=" & userDN & "))"
```

I am not sure about the problem with sAMAccountName as you have not included an example.

Comment: Thank you! Simple mistake, everything works now. However, I'm getting the DN of the groups rather than the CN. Is there any way to get the CN of the groups to be displayed?

Comment: I believe you have to add the properties you want to retrieve to the searcher.